# Looking for Java EE video tutorials

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, ejb

I'm looking for paid video tutorials like this one : `Video2Brain Java EE 6`

[image]

It has nice videos, but the problem is that they are in german.

So, I was wondering if any someone of you knows something like that.

I tried http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/ but they don't have Server configuration ans JSP, Servlet programming.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can find something in any of these sites:

- [Learn Now Java](http://www.learnnowjava.com/)
- [O'Reilly Videos](http://oreilly.com/videos/programming.html)
- [Safari Videos](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/video)

Comment: +1 for O'Reilly, also http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses#java , http://www.lynda.com/search?q=java

Answer (score 2):

I've just about finished the virtualpairprogrammers JavaEE 6 course and it's really good. The thing that I like about it the most is that Dick Chesterwood takes you through various aspects of developing an application, including design considerations as well.

One thing that I can't stand about some courses out there, particularly a lot of books, is that you get to learn a lot of technical things, but in isolation. It is hard to find something more practical that pieces things together.

It's a bit expensive though at $399US. Still, I didn't mind paying for it as it does deliver what I really needed to know (at least at that particular time). It would be great if they made a more advanced version to offer more detail. JavaEE is obviously quite a large suite.

They also have a Java web developer course, but I'm not sure whether that would have much benefit after having done the JavaEE 6 course.

I saw some of the video2brain lessons that you mentioned above. It looks really professional. I even considered trying to learn enough German just to get by with the course.

I'm now looking for other options to further my knowledge of JavaEE. If I find anything, I'll come back and post it up.

Comment: Thanks but it's too cheap for something not professional like  `Video2Brain`

Comment: Can you share few lessons of vpp training?